# What is the difference between find and locate?

Tags: macos, find, locate

It seems to me `locate` is **much** faster than `find` and also more thorough at finding files. What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell - `find` goes over the directory it is given (recursively) and looks for files that match the given criteria. `locate`, on the other hand, uses a pre-prepared database(s) previously created by `updatedb`. It stands to reason that `locate` should be faster, but it's less accurate, since the database it uses may be out of date, and may no longer reflect the actual file system.

Comment: If I find myself needing to do a bunch of searching, I'll kick off a `updatedb` beforehand.